# Прочитать объект из файла прямо в его методе C++

Tags: c++, файлы, методы, this

Мне нужно записать записывать/считывать объект из файла, используя функции fwrite() и fread(). Могу ли я создать такие методы в классе:

```
class Foo
{
public:

    void saveToFile(const char *filename) const
    {
        FILE *file = fopen(filename, "wb");

        //Функция fwrite() не модифицирует данные,
        //на которые указывать this. Все должно быть хорошо.
        fwrite(this, sizeof(*this), 1, file);

        fclose(file);
    }

    void loadFromFile(const char *filename)
    {
        FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb");

        //Функция fread() модифицирует данные,
        //на которые указывает this. 
        //Это происходит прямо в методе класса,
        //который сейчас будет читаться из файла.
        //Безопасно ли это делать?
        fread(this, sizeof(*this), 1, file);

        fclose(file);
    }

};
```

И рассчитывать, что все будет работать хорошо? В коде могут быть упущены и другие моменты, но меня интересует только чтение в память по указателю `this` прямо в методе класса. Можно ли так делать?

Comment: Ну, если это POD, при этом без каких-то виртуальностей и наследований, то, наверное, сработает... Но я бы все же поостерегся. Я бы, пожалуй, собрал данные (если это POD) в одну внутреннюю структуру и писал/читал ее.

Comment: если объект класса содержит только фундаментальные типы (int, float, double) и c-массивы, то проблем быть не должно. Но лучше все-таки использовать `xml` или `json` для сериализации объктов

Comment: В пределах одной машины проблем быть не должно для POD структур. Но при передаче на другие могут возникнуть две проблемы: может различаться выравнивание полей и порядок байт. Первая проблема решается перебором элементарных полей и вызовом функции сериализации/десериализации для каждого. Вторая решается переносимой реализацией этих функций сериализации/десериализации. К сожалению, в С++ нет стандартных средств управления порядком байт, но можно использовать функции операционной системы типа htonll . Нормального способа обойти все элементарный поля тоже нет. Рекомендую гуглить c++ serialization

Answer (score -1):

В пределах одной машины проблем быть не должно для POD структур. Но при передаче на другие могут возникнуть две проблемы: может различаться выравнивание полей и порядок байт. Первая проблема решается перебором элементарных полей и вызовом функции сериализации/десериализации для каждого. Вторая решается переносимой реализацией этих функций сериализации/десериализации. К сожалению, в С++ нет стандартных средств управления порядком байт, но можно использовать функции операционной системы типа htonll . Нормального способа обойти все элементарный поля тоже нет. Рекомендую гуглить c++ serialization